# Is There an SSIS Component that can perform dynamic updates during insertion?

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I have a table with potentially billions of records. The requirement is to set certain fields for a group of records within the table to a previous value until that value changes, then replace the previous value with the new value.

Consider the following as an example of the records being retrieved from the original source:

EventSeqNo
    EventDesc
      DescId
      Desc2Id
      Desc3Id
      Desc4Id
      Desc5Id

1
                     EventOne
           1
              102
               1
                 1
                1

2
                     EventTwo
         2862
            1
                 1
                 1
              131

3
                     EventThree
        1
                1
                 1
                 1
                1

6
                     Close
                 1
               102
               1
               102
              1

1
                     EventOne
           1
              105
               1
                 1
                1

2
                     EventTwo
         2873
            1
                  1
                1
              131

3
                     EventThree
         1
             101
              106
              1
                1

6
                     Close
                  1
               1
                  1
               102
              1

The desired output after insertion into the final table would be:

EventSeqNo
    EventDesc
      DescId
      Desc2Id
      Desc3Id
      Desc4Id
      Desc5Id

1
                     EventOne
           1
              102
               1
                 1
                1

2
                     EventTwo
         2862
          102
               1
                 1
              131

3
                     EventThree
      2862
          102
               1
                 1
              131

6
                     Close
               2862
           102
               1
               102
            131

1
                     EventOne
           1
              105
               1
                 1
                1

2
                     EventTwo
         2873
          105
                 1
                 1
              131

3
                     EventThree
      2873
          101
              106
              1
              131

6
                     Close
               2873
           101
              106
           102
             131

As you can see, each field should acquire the value of the previous field's record unless it is a value of one. Also, the range of records that repeat this rule are grouped and range from 1 through 6 as the Event value.

Is there an SSIS component that can gracefully accomplish this task during the initial record insertions with minimal complexity as opposed to performing complex SQL updates to the table after it's population?

It was suggested to me that the Cache Transform task may be the solution but after reading up on how to implement it, it doesn't seem to be the appropriate solution for the problem.

If there isn't any SSIS package task that could accomodate as a solution, what are some other possible alternatives? I am open to any reasonable suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: The biggest problem I see id that there is no identifier except record order to determine which records go together. Record order is never guaranteed in inserting records into a table.

Comment: I concur with that HLGEM. But suppose those records wtere inserted into a table that has an identity field as the identifier and the order of the records were still retained. Would you see any possible alternatives under those circumstances (SSIS or otherwise)??

Comment: how are you going to guarantee the order of insert?

Comment: I have developed a query that orders the data by two other fields (not shown) and the EventId prior to table insertion. The method works flawlessly, in fact the 1st example I provided comes directly from the target table without any order by statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can guarantee the order of insert, I would insert the data into a staging table that has an identity and a column for parent id (with null values to start). Then I would use Execute SQL tasks in SSIS to transform the data (first setting the parent id value (so each related task had a column telling it the first task in the group) making it simpler to do the transforms). After transforimg the data in the staging table, then I would do a simple data flow from the staging table to the final table. However, if there was any chance of chagning the csv to add a column to group the records together, I would insist on that, sooner or later some of these will get out of order otherwise.